# Proof for palindrome grammar by induction

Tags: formal-languages, finite-automata

I can't seem to find a solution to the following question.

> Given the following grammar for palindromes:
>             $$G_{pal}=\{\{a,\dots,z\},\{P\},P,R\},$$ with $R$ consisting of the rules
>             $$P \to \epsilon \mid a \mid aPa\text{ for every }a \in \Sigma.$$
>
> Prove that every palindrome $w$ is in $L(G_{pal})$:
>
> $$w = w^r \longrightarrow w \in L(G_{pal}).$$

Comment: Please show what you tried, where exactly you see yourself stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show $w\in L(G_{Pal})$, Show with induction on **word length** the lemma: "If $w=w^R$ then $P\rightarrow...\rightarrow w$"

- basis is simple. Do it yourself.
- assume $|w|=n+1$ and we know that every $\hat w$ with $\hat w = \hat w^R, |\hat w|\le n$ satisfies, $P\rightarrow...\rightarrow \hat w.$ Then:
  define $\hat w:=w_{2,...,n}$. since $w=w^R$ then also $\hat w = \hat w^R$. But $|\hat w|\le n$, thus $P\rightarrow...\rightarrow \hat w$. Now we can derive $w$ since we know we can derive $w'$: 
  $P\rightarrow w_1Pw_1\rightarrow w_1Pw_{n+1}\rightarrow...\rightarrow w_1\hat ww_{n+1}=w$

We have shown that $w$ can be constructed from $P$ in the grammer. So $w=w^R\rightarrow w\in L(G_{Pal})$

Note that in order to show that this grammer is correct, **this is not enough.** you will need to also show that $w\in L(G_{Pal})\rightarrow w=w^R$

Comment: thank you so much kind person

Comment: no problem. This is the reason StackExchange exists in the first place :)